# How to find the maximum element of list?

Tags: r, max

I have a big list and I want to find the maximum element of it, but it seems that doesn't work. Would someone help me?

A part of my list:

```
>X
    [[722]]
    [1] 3489

    [[723]]
    [1] 3100

    [[724]]
    [1] 3520

    [[725]]
    [1] 3544

    [[726]]
    [1] 3476

    [[727]]
    [1] 3625

    [[728]]
    [1] 3305
```

and here is my effort:

```
lapply(X, FUN=max )
```

But it does not give me the single number, which is the largest entry of this list, for example. Here I would expect to get **3625** as output.

Comment: Use the `max` function

Answer (score 25):

You should `unlist` before applying `max`:

```
max(unlist(X))
```